# invalid prop value of type number supplied to textinput expected string react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am create a word count for a textinput in react native, I think I have been able to achieve the word count, however, when i type into the textinput, I am getting an error of 'invalid prop value of type number supplied to textinput expected string react native'. I have tried everything i can to no avail

```
        constructor(props) {
          super(props);
          this.state = {
            ModalVisibleStatus: false,
            maxLength: 70,
            charLength: 70,
            messageValue: '',
          };
        }


        onChangeMessage(messageValue) {
          const input = messageValue;
          const charLength = this.state.maxLength - input.length.toString();
          this.setState({
            charLength,
            messageValue: charLength
          });
        }


        <TextInput
          placeholder={placeholder}
          onChangeText={this.onChangeMessage.bind(this)}
          value={this.state.messageValue}
          autoFocus
          autoCorrect
          multiline
          maxLength={this.state.maxLength}
          style={styles.textInputStyle}
          underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        />
        <Text style={{ textAlign: 'right', right: 5, }}>{this.state.messageValue}</Text>
```

Comment: Textinput value you pass is int not string. This could help **onChangeMessage(messageValue) {
          const input = messageValue;
          const charLength = this.state.maxLength - input.length.toString();
          this.setState({
            charLength,
            messageValue: String(charLength)
          });
        }*

Comment: I have tried it this way before and I am getting the number value instead of the text i am inputting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You update state with number value in onChangeMessage function.

There are two way to correct it.

1. Update Your onChangeMessage function in this way

   `onChangeMessage(messageValue) {
    const input = messageValue;
    const charLength = this.state.maxLength - input.length.toString();
    this.setState({
    charLength,
     messageValue: input
         });
       }`
2. Write charLength in `${charLength}` this way while updating state.

And I think you are doing something wrong by updating input value with length. you should update input value with what user enter in input field

Comment: I have tried it this way before and I am getting the number value instead of the text i am inputting

how do you suggest i update the input value

Comment: Then you need to update messageValue with input not charLength